# Java expression for Pentaho Kettle

Tags: java, expression, pentaho, kettle, pdi

I m in a precarious situation. I am looking for a 'JAVA EXPRESSION' for replacing a defined 'place-holder' in kettle.

My incoming string A is

```
<consumers>
 ?place-holder?
</consumers>
```

My incoming string Y is

```
<consumer>
   <info>X</info> 
 </consumer>
```

After substitution the final output must be

```
<consumers>
   <consumer>
     <info>X</info>
   </consumer>  
</consumers>
```

Basically I am substituting ?place-holder? in 'String A' with 'String B'.

Actually the data's volume is extremely high and hence 'javascript', 'calculator' & 'replace in string' and all other options that I have tried is pathetic in performance.

I have read that 'Java expressions' are high in performance. Somehow, I am not able to come up with the expression.

Any help!

Comment: Have you tried `Regex Evaluation` and/or `XML Join`?

Comment: XML join is pathetic in performance. That I tried very first. Regex is also low in performance. Also, not able to come up with any accurate REGEX. :(

Comment: If your input is a well-formed XML then I'd better use XML Input Stream (StAX) step, i.e. SAX parser. It's fast.

Answer (score 0):

Try it out. Self explained picture below

[image]

Don't forget to check with java doc to string what expression does actually.

> Replaces **each** substring of this string that matches the

Comment: Thanks for your time. But I am not able to open the image. when I click, it says 'invalid response'.

Comment: It is in here https://i.stack.imgur.com/MirgB.png. Might be website www.imgur.com is down. Try it later.